# What is the time complexity of the EMST problem in 3D space

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, spanning-trees

We have an unstructured cloud of $N$ points in 3D space. What is known about the complexity of building the Euclidean Minimum Spanning Tree of the points ?

The tree is made of $N-1$ edges and can be built as a subset of the Delaunay triangulation in time $O(N^2)$, but I don't think that this is tight.

Answer (score 1):

The current [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree&oldid=1094988780#Higher_dimensions) has information:

> For three dimensions it is possible to find the minimum spanning tree in time $O((n \log⁡ n)^{4/3})$

And about approximation:

> it is possible to produce a $(1 + \varepsilon)$-approximation in $O(n \log n)$ time, whenever $\varepsilon$ is a constant.

In practice, worst-case quadratic algorithms are used because worst-case inputs are rare and fast enough most of the time.